# Openstack vm are unable to reach to internet

Tags: linux-networking

I have installed and configured the OpenStack on Ubuntu 18.04 OS with two-node by splitting services as per in below,

Controller node - Maria DB – mysqlrabbitMQ and memcacheKeystoneHorizonGlanceNovaCinder – Block Storage – Initial Setup – Block Storage SchedulerSwift – Object Storage initial Setup Heat Orchestration

Computer node - NovaCinder – Block StorageStore1

Please kindly help me to resolve the neutron issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KrLf.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDeZv.jpg)

Comment: From the Controller Node,

Comment: From the Controller Node, all network agents are up and running. Linux bridge agent, Metadata agent,  L3 agent, DHCP agent, Linux bridge agent

Comment: nova-scheduler, nova-conductor,nova-compute  up and running when i launch openstack compute service list command